# ValueError: shapes (4,) and (1008,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 0) != 1008 (dim 0)

Tags: numpy

Kindly help me with use of this numpy.dot function in the code below. I think it has something to do with the shape of the arguments being out of sync.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()

tickers = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'META']
start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2022-01-01'
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start_date, end_date)['Adj Close']

returns = np.array(df.iloc[:,1:])
#cov_matrix = np.cov(returns.T)

weights = np.random.uniform(size = (4,))
#x = np.array([1,2,3,4])

print("The shape of returns is", returns.shape)
print("The shape of weights is", weights.shape)
weights /= np.sum(weights)


population_size = 10
num_assets = 4
population = []
for i in range(population_size):
    weights = np.random.uniform(size=(num_assets,))
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    population.append(weights)
print(population[1].shape)
print(np.dot(population[1].T, returns))
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for the np.dot function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right. To perform the dot product of two arrays/matrices `X * Y`, the last dimension of `X` must be equal to the first dimension of `Y`. To check this in Python, you can use `assert X.shape[-1] == Y.shape[0]`

So the ValueError you're getting tells you they're not aligned. Transposing the second array (`returns`) would fix it - if that's the computation you meant to do.